# java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Tengo un pequeño problema que no logró entender, es que mi aplicación me esta dando el siguiente error después de haber programado el `Web Service`. aquí dejo el código:

```
public class Winery {
    private static final String wineURL = "http://static.keepcoding.io/baccus/wines.json";

private static Winery sInstance = null;

private List<Wine> mWines = null;

public static Winery getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
            sInstance = downloadWines();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //else
    return sInstance;
}

private static Winery downloadWines() throws IOException, JSONException {
    Winery winery = new Winery();
    winery.mWines = new LinkedList<>();

    URLConnection conn = new URL(wineURL).openConnection();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
    }
    reader.close();


    JSONArray wines = new JSONArray(reader.toString());

    for (int wineIndex = 0; wineIndex < wines.length(); wineIndex++) {
        String name = null;
        String type = null;
        String company = null;
        String companyWeb = null;
        String notes = null;
        int rating = 0;
        String origin = null;

        JSONObject jsonWine = wines.getJSONObject(wineIndex);
        if (jsonWine.has("name")) {
            name = jsonWine.getString("name");
            type = jsonWine.getString("type");
            company = jsonWine.getString("company");
            companyWeb = jsonWine.getString("companyWeb");
            notes = jsonWine.getString("notes");
            rating = jsonWine.getInt("rating");
            origin = jsonWine.getString("origin");

            Wine wine = new Wine(name, type, R.drawable.bembibre, company, companyWeb, notes, origin, rating);
            JSONArray jsonGrapes = jsonWine.getJSONArray("grapes");
            for (int grapeIndex = 0; grapeIndex < jsonGrapes.length(); grapeIndex++) {
                wine.addGrape(jsonGrapes.getJSONObject(grapeIndex).getString("grape"));

            }
            winery.mWines.add(wine);
        }
    }

    return winery;
}


public Winery(){

        //Creating wines.
        Wine bembibre =new Wine(

                "Bembibre",
                "Tinto",
                R.drawable.bembibre,
                "Dominio de Tares",
                "http://www.dominiodetares.com/portfolio/bembibre/",
                "Este vino muestra toda la complejidad y la elegancia de la variedad Mencía. En fase visual luce un color rojo picota muy cobierto con tonalidades violáceas en el menisco. En nariz aparecen recuerdos frutales muy intensos de frutas rojas (frambuesa, cereza) y una potente ciruela negra asi como tonos florales de la gama de las rosas y violetas, vegetales muy elegantes y complementarios, hojarasca verde, tabaco y maderas aromáticas (sándalo) que le brindan un troque ciertamente perfumado",
                "El Bierzo",
                5);
        bembibre.addGrape("Mencía");

        Wine vegaval =new Wine(
                "Vegaval",
                "Tinto",
                R.drawable.vegaval,
                "Miguel de Calatayud",
                "http://www.vegaval.com/es",
                "Un vino de esmerado proceso de elaboración y larga crianza. Presenta un color rojo cereza con matices a teja y una brillante capa media alta. Nariz compleja, fina y elegante. Es excelentemente estructurado, amplio y muy sabroso. Recomendado para acompañar quesos curados, estofados y todo tipo de carnes rojas y de caza. La temperatura recomendada para servir está¡ entre los 16º C y 18º C.",
                "Valdepeñas",
                4);
        vegaval.addGrape("Tempranillo");

        Wine zarate =new Wine(
                "Zarate",
                "Blanco",
                R.drawable.zarate,
                "Miguel de Calatayud",
                "http://bodegas-zarate.com/productos/vinos/albarino-zarate/",
                "El albariño Zarate es un vino blanco monovarietal que pertenece a la Denominación de Origen Rías Baixas. Considerado por la critica especializada como uno de los grandes vinos blancos del mundo, el albariño ya es todo un mito.",
                "Rias Bajas",
                5);
        zarate.addGrape("Albariño");

        Wine champagne =new Wine(
                "Champagne",
                "Otros",
                R.drawable.champagne,
                "Champagne Taittinger",
                "http://bodegas-zarate.com/productos/vinos/albarino-zarate/",
                "ùLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac nunc purus. Curabitur eu velit mauris. Curabitur magna nisi, ullamcorper ac bibendum ac, laoreet et justo. Praesent vitae tortor quis diam luctus condimentum. Suspendisse potenti. In magna elit, interdum sit amet facilisis dictum, bibendum nec libero. Maecenas pellentesque posuere vehicula. Vivamus eget nisl urna, quis egestas sem. Vivamus at venenatis quam. Sed eu nulla a orci fringilla pulvinar ut eu diam. Morbi nibh nibh, bibendum at laoreet egestas, scelerisque et nisi. Donec ligula quam, semper nec bibendum in, semper eget dolor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas adipiscing semper rutrum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae",
                "Comtes de Champagne",
                3);
        champagne.addGrape("Chardonnay");

        //Adding Wines by an Array
        mWines = Arrays.asList(new Wine[]{bembibre, vegaval, zarate, champagne});
    }

       public Wine getWine(int index) {
           return mWines.get(index);
       }
       public int getWineCount() {
           return mWines.size();
       }

       public List <Wine> getWineList(){
           return mWines;
       }
}
```

El error me lo esta dando aquí :

> at jhon.casique.baccus.controller.fragment.WineListFragment.onCreateView(WineListFragment.java:41)

```
public class WineListFragment extends Fragment {
    private OnWineSelectedListener mOnWineSelectedListener = null;


public WineListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wine_list, container, false);

    //Reference to ListView
    ListView listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    //Acceding Winery
    Winery winery = Winery.getInstance();

    //List adapter
    ArrayAdapter<Wine> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, winery.getWineList());

    //Saying the adapter to the listView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //What to do when the user press one item on the list.
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (mOnWineSelectedListener != null) {
                mOnWineSelectedListener.onWineSelected(i);
            }
        }
    });

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mOnWineSelectedListener= (OnWineSelectedListener) getActivity();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mOnWineSelectedListener = null;
}

public interface OnWineSelectedListener {
    void onWineSelected(int indexWine);
}
```

}

La linea 41 es esta:

```
   ArrayAdapter<Wine> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, winery.getWineList());
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar, se los agradezco.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente tu **winery.getWineList()** este nulo, inicializa el **winery** antes del **Adapter**

```
Winery winery = new Winery(); 

ArrayAdapter<Wine> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, winery.getWineList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Ten cuidado, que no está permitido realizar `request http` desde el `thread` principal. Deberías realizar la tarea en forma asíncrona, una alternativa es utilizar una *AsyncTask*. Para eso debes crear una clase que herede de *AsyncTask* y dentro del método `doInBackground` realizas el `request` y retornas el resultado. Luego, en el método `onPostExecute` recibes la respuesta que retornaste en el método anterior y ahí creas el adapter, y lo llenas con la información que ha respondido el servicio. Otra opción es utilizar alguna herramienta, como por ejemplo, *Volley* o *RetroFit*.

Answer (score 0):

El arreglo que obtiene este método probablemente tiene un valor Null, debe obtener un array de objetos `Wine`:

```
winery.getWineList()
```

Al llamar dentro de `onCreateView()` el método `Winery.getInstance();` en realidad no esta llenando el List de objetos `Wine` (`mWines`), trata llamando el constructor `Winery()` para inicializar el List.

```
Winery winery = new Winery();
```

antes de inicializar el Adapter.

Comment: No lo entiendo, debo llamar en el List al Winery??

Comment: Tu diseño es un poco raro, getInstance debería inicializar pero como tienes tu código tienes que hacer Winery winery = new Winery(); antes de usar el adapter.

Comment: Eso lo tengo pero en el modelo

Comment: private static Winery downloadWines() throws IOException, JSONException {
        Winery winery = new Winery();

Lo tengo que cambiar a otro lado o que? perdonen pero, no lo termino de entender porque me da error si esta todo correcto!!

Comment: El problema es que si ocurre un error en downloadWines() no va a retornar nada.

Comment: Vale lo voy a volver a ver, muchas gracias.